# MS Access 2010- How to update field on one table based on field in another table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm designing a database to track requests. Currently, I have a form that its' record source is based off a query "Unassigned Requests". This query is based off my table Requests, and returns all "unassigned Requests". In this form, I would like the status field to change to "Assigned", once a Tech field has been assigned to the request. I currently have the Default for the Tech Assigned field set to "Blank', and the status field set to 'Unassigned". Both of these fields are combo boxes. The status field has a control source from the request table and row source from the status table. The tech assigned field has a control source from the Tech table and the row source is based off a query.

I have tried multiple solutions that have not seemed to work. I have limited experience with Macros and VBA. I would appreciate any suggestions on solving this problem.

Comment: So what you want is to update a table from VBA, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I am not entirely sure how I would go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make some assumptions regarding your post and if any are incorrect please let me know.

You have a request form where a request is assigned to a Tech.  On that form there is a dropdown for the status, and also for the Tech.

You want to make it so when the tech dropdown is filled out with a tech's name you want the dropdown to change to assigned.

If this is the case I would recommend using the Tech Assigned field's AfterUpdate event.  The code would look something like this:

```
Private Sub cboTech_Assigned_AfterUpdate()

    If Nz(Me.cboTech_Assigned.Value, "") <> "" Then
        Me.cboStatus = "Assigned"
    Else
        Me.cboStatus = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Obviously you will need to adjust to your own naming scheme.  I should also point out that I don't even know if that Nz function is needed, I have just gotten into the habit of putting it everywhere. If I misunderstood something about what you want to do please let me know!